# How to address a html attribute in cypress?

Tags: html, testing, cypress

I have a html-element, that has the following attribute:
`ng-reflect-name="arrow-down-circle"`

How can I check with cypress, if this attribute has the text "arrow-down-circle"?

Below is the whole html-element:
`<ion-icon _ngcontent-wyk-c151="" slot="start" name="arrow-down-circle" color="primary" ng-reflect-name="arrow-down-circle" ng-reflect-color="primary" aria-label="arrow down circle" role="img" class="md ion-color ion-color-primary hydrated"></ion-icon>`

(I am really new to cypress, so I apologize for any naive question!)

I have tried two commands, but both were wrong:

1.: `cy.get(filter_popover).find('#ng-reflect-name').should('contain.text', 'arrow-down-circle');` 
2.: `cy.get(filter_popover).find('[data-cy=btn_selectDesc]').invoke('attr', 'ng-reflect-name').should('contain.text', 'arrow-down-circle');`

(filter_popover is a constante, that contains a specific page where the html-element is located and data-cy=btn_selectDesc is the identifier of the html-element one hierarchy step above)

Answer (score 1):

You can try to check attribute value using `have.attr`, more examples can be found [here](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/contains#Favor-of-lt-a-gt-over-other-deeper-elements).

```
cy.get('ion-icon').should('have.attr', 'ng-reflect-name', 'arrow-down-circle')
```

Answer (score 0):

One simple option is to use the value as part of your `get` selector

```js
// any element with the attribute
cy.get('[ng-reflect-name="arrow-down-circle"]').should("exist")

// only ion-icon elements with the attribute
cy.get('ion-icon[ng-reflect-name="arrow-down-circle"]').should("exist")
```

In your example I see `.find('[data-cy=btn_selectDesc]')`. When using attributes as selectors, make sure you include the quotes. (`.find('[data-cy="btn_selectDesc"]')`)